# Titanium Android SDK

Tags: android, titanium

I tried many things to setup Android SDK on Titanium (3.2.0 GA) but I couldn't. I installed Android 4.4.2 (API 19) and latest Android SDK tools on my computer (Windows 8). I setup an AVD. Also I tried to install Android NDK. But Titanium doesn't want to see the emulator and gives the error: [Android SDK Home] No Android SDKs were found underr the specified SDK location
In the dashboard it says "Items required:"
•An Android SDK is missing. Titanium requires Android platform 5.0
•Add-On addon.+google.+apis.+10

What is Androd Platform 5.0?

Answer (score 3):

Google apis 10 is Android 2.3.3.  I had trouble with the initial setup after the 3.2.0 upgrade also.

In the Android SDK Manager under tools I have installed:

- Android SDK Tools Rev 22.3
- Android SDK Platform-tools Rev 19.0.1
- Android SDK Build-tools Rev 19.0.1

In the Android SDK Manager under Android 2.3.3 I have installed:

- SDK Platform
- Samples for SDK
- Intel x86 Atom System Image
- Google APKs

I also have Android 4.4.2 (API 19) installed with:

- Documentation for Android SDK
- SDK Platform
- Samples for SDK
- ARM EABI v7a System Image
- Google APIs

For the ndk I have revision 9.

I don't know for certain if this will resolve your issue, but if not I would run `titanium setup check` in the command line to try to dig deeper into the environment setup information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have exactly same tools, 4.4.2 components and NDK. I also installed 2.3.3 as you said. Restarted Titanium but it didn't work. In Run Configuration it still says " [Android SDK Home] No Android SDKs were found underr the specified SDK location". You can see installed SDKs [here](http://napptune.com/temp/android-sdk.PNG)

Comment: I know it shouldn't make a difference but myself and some of my co-workers installed the daily build Studio IDE.  It fixed issues for us with deploying to android devices and emulators.  Maybe it would help you.  Under install new software in the help menu.  I added a site http://preview.appcelerator.com/appcelerator/studio/standalone/update/rc/ that alerts me with the updates.

Comment: First of all I updated Titanium Studio 3.2.0 to 3.2.1. It didn't solve my problem. I reviewed the [Setup Docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Setting_up_Studio). I installed JDK and node.js again. Then I added node.js to the PATH variable as said in [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Software_Locations_and_Environment_Variables-section-29004844_SoftwareLocationsandEnvironmentVariables-WindowsSoftwareLocations) Now I can see that Android is installed.I don't know which action solved it.

Answer (score 2):

I've done all the things above and after experimenting I've come up with a solution,
I'm using window 7, and I deleted the file at C:/Users/MyName/.titanium/config.json.

it works well for me try it and restart your titanium

by the way i'm using ti studio 3.2.3

Answer (score 0):

After installing Titanium Studio, build: 3.2.0.201312191547 I also had a problem with setting up Android SDK. Tried re-downloading ASDK, tried choosing API 5 and API 10, as suggested in various posts - didn't work.

SOLUTION I FOUND WORKING: reseting directoris for NodeJS (Window/Preferences/Studio/NodeJS). For Node Executive - path to node.exe, for Node source I have selected 'Download'. After download I had to browse to the actual path - system chose automatically one with inverted '\'. After restart - it's working!
Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things that helped me solve this problem:

1) Install a continuous build of Titanium from here --> [Continuous Builds](http://builds.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html#3_2_X)

2) Follow the steps that are shown here --> [Installing Continuous Builds](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Installing+Titanium+SDK+Continuous+Builds)

3) Copy the below files from the 'platform tools' folder in the android sdk folder into the 'tools' subfolder.

- adb.exe
- AdbWinApi.dll
- AdbWinUsbApi.dll

Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I found and specific solution to my same problem, once any of the other solutions worked. My problem was the Genymotion emulator (I had it installed, but I uninstalled it):

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-4438

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I broke my head for 2 days on the very same problem, and the solution is quite simple:
Titanium 3.2 and above does not work with android sdk in Windows.

Downgrade to 3.1.3 and everything will be just fine

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Reverting+to+a+Previous+Version

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem and I found that in my case this was caused by the Java version.
Make sure that Java 7 32 bit is the default system java version. Open command prompt and execute:

```
c:\>java -version
```

The expected output should be:

```
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Make sure that the last line doesn't contain "64-Bit" like:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

My default Java version was 64-bit and at first I just added -vm argument in TitaniumStudio.ini pointing to the 32-bit Java. It turned out that this was not enough. The default system Java version needs to be the 32-bit.